# If $P(x)=x^{n+1}-2x^n+1\forall n\geq2$ and $P(x)$ has a unique root $a_n\in(1,2]$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n(2-a_n)=?$

Tags: limits

> If $P(x)=x^{n+1}-2x^n+1\forall n\geq2$ and $P(x)$ has a unique root $a_n\in(1,2]$, then $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n(2-a_n)=?$

---

As $P(x)=0\implies x^{n+1}-2x^n+1=0\implies x-2+1/x^n=0\implies $as $n\to\infty,x\to2$. So, $a_n^{n+1}-2a_n^{n}+1=0\implies a_n^n(2-a_n)=1$
So we might say $L=1$ but according to me it's wrong because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n(2-a_n)\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}2_n^n(2-a_n)$ because we have substituted $a_n=2$, why not then we say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n(2-a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}2_n^n(2-2)=0$, this depends on $f(x)$ where $a(n)=2+O(f(n))$. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\color{red}{L=1}$$ Note that $2^n(2-a_n)=\left(\frac2{a_n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}\right)^n$. Since $a_n\to2$, $\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}\ll\frac1n$, hence $\left(1+\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}\right)^n\to1$.

Comment: $\left(\frac2{a_n}\right)^n\stackrel{?how?}=\left(1+\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}\right)^n$

Comment: Because $$\frac2{a_n}=1+\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: that's nothing new, tell me $\frac2{a_n}\stackrel{???}=1+\frac1{a_n^{n+1}}.$

Comment: oh you divided the equation by that and got this?

Comment: "that's nothing new" Are you trying to be rude? The identity in my comment answers the query in your comment and is strictly equivalent to $P_n(a_n)=0$.

Comment: sorry but I was confused how you wrote the identity in your second comment, because i knew that $a=b\implies a^n=b^n$.after knowing the reason I wished you said that divide the equation by $a_n^{n+1}$. Anyways if I felt being rude, I apolozize